# How to create a new list of all the words separating by each word and each line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a text file as :

sample.txt

```
Hi I am student
I am from
```

What I've tried is

```
import string
import re

def read_to_list1(filepath):
    text_as_string = open(filepath, 'r').read()
    x = re.sub('['+string.punctuation+']', '', text_as_string).split("\n")
    
    for i in x:
        x_as_string = re.sub('['+string.punctuation+']', '', i).split()
        print(x_as_string)

read_to_list1('sample.txt')
```

This results

```
['Hi,'I','am','student']
['I','am','from']
```

I want the result as:

```
[['Hi,'I','am','student'],['I','am','from']]
```

Comment: What is the deal with all the `string.punctuation` handling? Can you show an example of what you are trying to handle for those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening the file, you can use a list comprehension to iterate over lines, and for each line `str.split` on whitespace to get tokens for each sublist.

```
def read_to_list1(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f_in:
        return [line.split() for line in f_in]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the specific example sample.txt, this should also work:

```
import string
import re

def read_to_list1(filepath):
    text_as_string = open(filepath, 'r').read()
    x = re.sub('['+string.punctuation+']', '', text_as_string).split("\n")
    final_array=[]
    for i in x:
        x_as_string = re.sub('['+string.punctuation+']', '', i).split()
        final_array.append(x_as_string)
    return final_array    
print(read_to_list1('sample.txt'))
```